# unsigned int a; while(a-- != 0) and while(a-- > 0) , which "while" will be faster?

Tags: c, linux, arm

I want to know, with `unsigned int a;`, if `while(a-- != 0)` and `while(a-- > 0)` will take same time and number of instructions to execute or not.

Which one is better to use?

Comment: Compile and disassemble and investigate the output. The C standard doesn't say anything about the number of instructions, so it depends on the compiler, etc.

Comment: You could also use `while(a--)`

Comment: Best would be to use the [arrow operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator): `while (a --> 0)`...

Comment: @AnT, the question specifies uint.

Comment: ...but, yeah. Could in theory depend on the compiler and the instruction set, but in practice, neither will be faster (and someone focusing on this kind of microoptimization is ignoring the structural areas of their code which they *should* be paying attention to instead).

Comment: At least some versions of gcc [output the same thing](https://goo.gl/Rd7zYD).

Answer (score 2):

The concept of "faster" or "slower" is not applicable to C code. C language constructs do not have any specific "speed" associated with them. Only the resultant machine code can be analyzed for speed.

If `a` is of unsigned type, any self-respecting compiler should generate identical code for both versions. "Greater than zero" and "not equal to zero" are equivalent comparisons for unsigned values.

Even if some compiler decides to translate it literally, for many modern platforms the difference would be just one specific conditional jump instruction. The performance would be the same anyway.

Comment: "premature optimization" ...

Answer (score 1):

They both take the same time and for `unsigned int a` will probably generate the same code anyway.

Regarding the second question, I would favor the second:

```
while(a-- > 0)
```

For 2 reasons:

- it is more readable: it makes it obvious to the reader that `a` will go down from the initial value to `0` inclusive.
- it is more consistent because it has the same behaviour for `signed` and `unsigned` values.  You can use this idiom for all downward iterations, the loop will be skipped correctly if `a` is `signed` and has a negative initial value.

Comment: Agree about preference for `a-- > 0`.  Any time `!` is used, it takes a small extra level of understanding, "unless you don't not disagree".